# Should I need to play Pokemon SuMo before Pokemon Ultra SuMo?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon, pokemon-ultra-sun-ultra-moon

I was speaking to a friend who recommended I do so. But I was looking for some extra opinions.

My experiences with the 1st 3 generations of pokemon gave me the opinion that pokemon wasn't really a plot heavy game (though lore/trivia can be surprisingly deep). The games are generally formulaic (gotta catch 'em all, 8 badges, a rival who usually takes a starter super effective against yours, a criminal organisation to wreck, an elite 4 and a champion to beat) Only big surprise I can recall with nostalgia googles in full effect is gen 2's double region. From what I vaguely recall reading SuMo was surprisingly plot heavy apparently.

My original plan was to just play Ultra SuMo as a remaster. Some of what I've read said I won't lose out on much by just playing Ultra, besides neatly seeing subversions of what happens in SuMo/the rest of the series? (One that I'm not sure might have been is rival picking a starter weak to mine).

Comment: One misunderstanding I want to clear up: the latest Pokemon games actually have a lot more plot to them than the earlier games. The core formula is still there, but these days, there are tons of side quests and side activities to complete, and you even have friends from your hometown who you regularly interact with, both through battles and through quests/dialogue. The villainous teams also have more exotic motivations: Where Team Rocket in gen1/2 just wanted to make money (essentially mafia with pokemon), the later teams have goals of ecoterrorism, ending the world and taking over the world.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plot of Ultra Sun and Ultra Moon is an alternate retelling of the plot of Sun and Moon. It is not a sequel like Black 2 and White 2 were to Black and White, so it can be fully enjoyed without having any knowledge of Sun and Moon.

In fact, I'd go as far as to say that since Sun and Moon have a very unfinished feeling to them, it is probably better to *not* play them before Ultra Sun and Ultra Moon.

Comment: Disagree with the unfinished feeling but the rest is accurate.

Comment: @Pyritie Gyms. Necrozma.

Comment: USUM only has one "gym" and it's just a gimmick. Necrozma was just a secret postgame mon -- plenty of other generations have had these. You don't need to play through an almost identical game again just for a slightly different ending.

Comment: (I have heard Sun and Moon and it's "sequels" are a whole lot more empty compared to their predecessors)

Comment: But, of course, if you asked the creators of pokemon, they would most certainly say "Yes, Please do buy both"